# Handling Many to Many relations in Chris Pratt's Truly Generic Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Basically, I'm trying to follow Chris Pratt's "Truly Generic Repository" ( http://cpratt.co/truly-generic-repository/ ) but don't know how to handle the Many-to-Many relationships within that generic repository. I do not want to add Attach method to the interface and then calling it from my service layer (I'm calling Chris Pratt's IRepository as IService) and basically all my service functions will be calling Service : IService. In other words, I do not want to call Attach method from within PersonService, I wish the Create/Update method in Service.cs (which is inheriting IRepository/IService) to handle Many-to-Many automatically without the involvment of consumer (i.e PersonService.cs).

Any thoughts?

my current code is the following and I don't know how to achieve the same effect using Chris Pratt's repository.

```
public int AddPerson(Person person)
{ 
    using (var dbContext = new MyContext("myConnString"))
    { 
        // Attaching Hobbies
        person.Hobbies.ToList().ForEach(x => dbContext.Hobbies.Attach(x));

        dbContext.People.Add(person);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return person.PersonId;
    }
}

public void UpdatePerson(Person person)
{ 
    using (var dbContext = new MyContext("myConnString"))
    {
        // Loading existing entity to compare
        Person existingPerson = FindPersonBy(true, x => x.PersonId == person.PersonId, new string[] { "Hobbies", "Gender" });

        dbContext.People.Attach(existingPerson);
        dbContext.Entry(existingPerson).CurrentValues.SetValues(person);

        // Updating Person.Hobbies
        var deletedHobbies = existingPerson.Hobbies.ExceptBy(person.Hobbies, x => x.HobbyId).ToList();
        deletedHobbies.ForEach(x => existingPerson.Hobbies.Remove(x));

        var addedHobbies = person.Hobbies.ExceptBy(existingPerson.Hobbies, x => x.HobbyId).ToList();
        addedHobbies.ForEach(x => { dbContext.Hobbies.Attach(x); existingPerson.Hobbies.Add(x); });

        // Saving Transaction
         dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to create an object and have a secondary object also created with it, you need to handle that in the signature.  EG: (Person person, Order order).  Then deal with a navigation that hooks up one to the other.  I am curious what you are talking about generic repository pattern though?  I am not seeing any generics you are using so why would you refer to a generic article?

Comment: The code that I pasted is not generic, that's my current code within the PersonService.cs. But I'm going to change that to generic by following the mentioned article, but before I jump I want to sure that the generic article mentioned does handle the Many to many relationships.